# Is it possible to start a chat with a user?

Tags: support, chat, users

I'd like to start something like a private chat room and invite a user to it to discuss possible research. Is this possible on Stack Exchange?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Is it possible to delete a chat room like that too? I might be inclined to share an email at some point, but I wouldn't prefer that be publicly available permanently., just for a short period of time.

Comment: @StackQuest Do note that anyone can see chat rooms you create, just only some people may post (although there are a few very special chat rooms, like the Teachers Lounge, that are truly private, those aren't super relevant here). You could always put an email address on your profile, and remove it later.

Comment: Well, a chat is buried deeper in the network. Chances are no spam bots will check it if stackexchange has any kind of automated security, but I've seen chat rooms in other places get spammed before. There's bots that constantly scan the internet for stuff like that. Maybe I can stick to just deleting the comment rather than the room.

Comment: https://onetimesecret.com